# Concatenating characters in R

Tags: r

I have a set of characters "A" "B" "C" and I want them to become one word "ABC", with no spacing. When I use

```
paste('A','B','C',collapse='')
[1] "A B C "
```

I get this, however I do not want any spacing. I want it to be "ABC"

Answer (score 9):

Use `sep` instead of `collapse` :

```
R> paste('A','B','C',sep='')
[1] "ABC"
```

With recent versions of R you can also use `paste0`, which is slightly more efficient :

```
R> paste0('A','B','C')
[1] "ABC"
```

Comment: @agstudy `paste0` is just `paste` with `sep=""` as default instead of `sep=" "`. And slightly more efficient, if I believe the help page (which I tend to do).

Answer (score 3):

You was close, try this :

```
paste(c('A','B','C'),collapse='')
# [1] "ABC"
```

As an alternative solution ,  package `stringr` contains `str_c` which Join multiple strings into a single string. So you can do this :

```
 str_c('A','B','C',collapse='')
 # [1] "ABC"
```

Comment: +1 for the `stringr` solution. The opening brackets are missing in your code. Is it normal ?

Answer (score 2):

if you concatenate your letters in one vector then collapse would have worked:

```
 paste(c('A','B','C'), collapse='')
 #[1] "ABC"
```